# Vim: How to auto-sync custom syntax highlight rules when colorscheme changes?

Tags: vim

I am using [VOoM](http://vim-voom.github.com/) (it is probably not needed to know much about it to be able to answer my question, I'm just providing this info for context) and I have managed to write myself a couple of custom syntax highlight rules for specific content.

First, I am using a modeline to tell vim that a certain file is a VOoM outline, I have this at the bottom of such files:

```
/* vim: set syntax=myvoom : */
```

Second, I have a **/home/user/.vim/after/syntax/myvoom.vim** file, here's a snippet from it:

```
syn match voomTag "^tags:.*"
hi voomTag ctermfg=White ctermbg=Red guifg=White guibg=Red
```

In some outline nodes I have lines like:

```
tags: foo, bar, baz
```

to make the searching easier, the syntax highlight rule above just displays those lines with a custom foreground/background.

This works as expected with default colorscheme (**:colorscheme** in vim returns 'default').

When I want to try a custom colorscheme ([mustang](http://hcalves.deviantart.com/art/Mustang-Vim-Colorscheme-98974484) for example) and change it by doing **:colorscheme mustang**, the syntax highlight for my tag lines is lost.

I would like to understand why this happens.

Also, I would like to learn how to auto-sync these custom syntax rules (which are general, not specific to a certain colorscheme) when the colorscheme is changed. Do I have to check for this explicitly somehow, in myvoom.vim file? Like looking what colorscheme is active and have custom syntax highlight rules for different colorschemes or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why this happens is in `:highlight clear` (see `:help :highlight`) command, which is normally one of first commands executed by colorscheme. This command resets all highlighting, thus removing effect of your custom `:highlight` command.

To fix this you need to use one of `:autocmd` (see `help :autocmd`) events, `ColorScheme` (see `:help ColorScheme`), to execute your command after new colorscheme is loaded. After changes your `myvoom.vim` should look like this:

```
augroup VoomTagHighlight
  autocmd! ColorScheme *
         \ syn match voomTag "^tags:.*" |
         \ hi voomTag ctermfg=White ctermbg=Red guifg=White guibg=Red
augroup END
```

See also help on `:augroup` at `:help :augroup`.

If you want to have different highlight depending on current colorscheme, use `:highlight link` command (see `:help :highlight-link`) instead of specifying your own colors. For example linking it to `Error` highlight group would look like this:

```
augroup VoomTagHighlight
  autocmd! ColorScheme *
         \ syn match voomTag "^tags:.*" |
         \ hi! link voomTag Error
augroup END
```